# Where do I put the .js file when I create js interface with Graphene 2

Tags: jsf-2, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, jboss-arquillian, graphene2

I follow this tutorial https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ARQGRA2/JavaScript+Interface

Where do I put my helloworld.js file? I put it under webapp/resources/js/helloworld.js and I do

```
import org.jboss.arquillian.graphene.javascript.Dependency;
import org.jboss.arquillian.graphene.javascript.JavaScript;

@JavaScript("helloworld")
@Dependency(sources = "js/helloworld.js")
public interface HelloWorld {
    String hello();
}
```

and I got NPE when I inject

```
@JavaScript
private HelloWorld helloWorld;
```

Please help. Here is my POM, I use glassfish3.1

```
<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <version.org.jboss.arquillian>1.0.4.Final</version.org.jboss.arquillian>
    <version.org.jboss.arquillian.drone>1.2.0.Alpha2</version.org.jboss.arquillian.drone>
    <version.org.jboss.arquillian.graphene>1.0.0.Final</version.org.jboss.arquillian.graphene>
    <version.org.jboss.arquillian.graphene2>2.0.0.Alpha4</version.org.jboss.arquillian.graphene2>
</properties>


<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Arquillian Drone dependencies and Selenium dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-drone-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${version.org.jboss.arquillian.drone}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Arquillian Core dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${version.org.jboss.arquillian}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>     
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-drone-webdriver-depchain</artifactId>           
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.graphene</groupId>
        <artifactId>graphene-webdriver</artifactId>
        <version>${version.org.jboss.arquillian.graphene2}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.graphene</groupId>
        <artifactId>graphene-webdriver-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${version.org.jboss.arquillian.graphene2}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-glassfish-remote-3.1</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.CR4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>       
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1):

Graphene looks for a referenced JS files on the test classpath, so let's put your file in `src/test/resources/js/helloworld.js`.

Comment: If you don't want to copy production resources to the test path, is there another approach? For example: **src/main/webapp/resources/js/hello.js**?